# VBA for words between slashes file name

Tags: vba, excel

I built a macro that saves workbooks based on a list of names. 
I'm getting a saveAs error because some of the new list items, have / which are not allowed in a file name.

I need some help in writing a code that will do this: note, that the list of teams, names, leagues and cups changes every row.

```
  list item: team/ league
  what I want: league 

  list item: team / league / cup                    
  What I want: league-cup

  List item; team / league / cup / score
  what I want: league-cup-score
```

I have it working for the first scenario where there is only one / but can't figure out for rest.

```
 InStr(Value, "/") > 0 Then
 filename = Right(Value, (Len(Value) - InStr(Value, "/")))
 Else
 filename = Value
 End If
```

is what I got so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split, trim, and join:

```
Function MakeFileName(s As String) As String
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    v = Split(s, "/")
    n = UBound(v)
    ReDim w(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        w(i) = Trim(v(i))
    Next i
    MakeFileName = Join(w, "-")
End Function
```

For example:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print MakeFileName("team/ league")
    Debug.Print MakeFileName("team / league / cup")
    Debug.Print MakeFileName("team / league / cup / score")
End Sub
```

Output:

```
league
league-cup
league-cup-score
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution, this time using `InStr`. Edited to handle where no league is present.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim str1 As String: str1 = "list item: team/ league"
    Dim str2 As String: str2 = "list item: team / league / cup "
    Dim str3 As String: str3 = "List item; team / league / cup / score"

    Debug.Print getTeamText(str1)
    Debug.Print getTeamText(str2)
    Debug.Print getTeamText(str3)

End Sub

Function getTeamText(ByVal StringIn As String) As String
    Dim strPos  As Long
    Dim lookFor As String: lookFor = "league"

    strPos = InStr(1, LCase(StringIn), lookFor)

    If strPos > 0 Then
        getTeamText = Replace(Replace(Mid(StringIn, strPos, (Len(StringIn) - strPos) + 1), " ", ""), "/", "-")
    Else
        getTeamText = "Could not find match"
    End If
End Function
```

Output should be as expected.

Comment: Although a nice solution, this is data dependent. If there is no `"league"` in the `StringIn` the code will break with `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument`

Answer (score 2):

Using the code you already have, you can use the VBA replace function to replace "/" with "-"

```
filename = Replace(filename, "/", "-")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use REPLACE

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php

example:

```
Dim oldString as String
Dim newString as String
newString=Replace(oldString,"/","_")
```

Comment: Please avoid link only answers as they can be meaningless in case the link ever dies. Leaving the link is fine (for whatever reason it may be useful), however, also place meaningful content in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
filename = Join(Split(Replace(Replace(Value, " ", ""), "team/", ""), "/"), "-")
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: @JoeC, such explanations as "You could split, trim, and join" or "Yet another solution, this time using InStr. Edited to handle where no league is present." or "Using the code you already have, you can use the VBA replace function to replace "/" with "-"" or "You need to use REPLACE" are as much helpful as no explanation